# change the value of an amount

Tags: php, laravel

In an html page, I would like to recover the value of an amount and can change the value only in my admin panel.

In the file navbar.blade.php I have 250 which is the amount to edit for the example.

```
<div class="header-widgets hidden-xs" style="padding:0px;padding-top: 60px;">
   <div id="text-3" class="widget widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget">
            <div class="info-icon">
                <img src="/img/time.png">
                   <span style="font-size: 22px;color: #0d3863;font-weight: bold;"> &nbsp;250</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just seek to edit the amount (250) ... 
In my Controller named tarrifcontroller I have that.

```
public function edit(Tariff $tariff)
    {
        return view('admin.tariffs.edit', compact('tariff'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, Tariff $tariff)
    {
        $tariff->valeur =  strip_tags($request->input('amount'));
        $tariff->save();

        return redirect('/tariffs');
    }
```

In my edit.blade.php I have that

```
@section('content')
  <div class="px-content">
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-xs-center text-md-left text-nowrap">
          <h1><i class="px-nav-icon ion-android-apps"></i>Tarif {{$tariff->id}} </h1>
        </div>
        <hr class="page-wide-block visible-xs visible-sm">
        <!-- Spacer -->
        <div class="m-b-2 visible-xs visible-sm clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <form class="panel-body" action="/tariff/edit/{{$tariff->id}}" method="POST">
              @csrf

              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Amount</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$tariff->amount}}">
              </fieldset>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">MAJ</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

My problem is now in navbar.blade.php how should I do that 250 can interact with my edit / update function?

```
<span style="font-size: 22px;color: #0d3863;font-weight: bold;"> &nbsp;250</span>
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to use `form` and `input` elements:`<form method="post" action="{{route('route-name')}}>@csrf <input type="text" name="amount" value="{{$value}}"/></form>`

Comment: You could define eventlistener to `onchange` or `onkeyup` events of the `input` that would update it in realtime

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with laravel but i guess like any other php framework you can echo variable from controller to view

```
<span style="font-size: 22px;color: #0d3863;font-weight: bold;"> &nbsp;<?php echo $variable ?></span>
```

after some googling: You can pass data to the view using the with method.

```
return View::make('blog')->with('posts', $posts);
```